# synaptic package manager error

Tags: package-management

Having upgraded to 20.04 I get an error message when reloading in synaptic package manager.

W: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

There are also another 3 similar W:'s relating to bionic all with the the DEPRECATION apt-key(8). Just showing the first to save space.

Is there a fix for this I can type into terminal?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your prompt to run man apt-key which I had no idea about. There is indeed a description although no explanation of what DEPRECATION really means. There are no instructions in terms of what I actually need to type into terminal to solve the problem that I have with synaptic.